# Submenus are not showing in angular when using menu-link menu-toggle class from bootstrap 5

Tags: html, jquery, angular, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to migrate my bootstrap html template to angular. I tried manage to bring out the design part, but submenus are not working when I clicked the main menu.

My codings in index.html :

```
<html
  lang="en"
  class="light-style layout-navbar-fixed layout-menu-fixed layout-menu-collapsed"
  dir="ltr"
  data-theme="theme-default"
  data-assets-path="/assets/"
  data-template="vertical-menu-template"
>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Templates</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">   
  <!--<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.2/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>-->
  <script src="/assets/vendor/js/helpers.js"></script>    
  <!--<script src="/assets/vendor/js/template-customizer.js"></script>-->
  <script src="/assets/js/config.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/css-toggle-switch/latest/toggle-switch.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-VHvPCCyXqtD5DqJeNxl2dtTyhF78xXNXdkwX1CZeRusQfRKp+tA7hAShOK/B/fQ2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>  
    <script src="/assets/vendor/libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script>   
    <script src="/assets/vendor/libs/popper/popper.js"></script>  
    <script src="/assets/vendor/js/bootstrap.js"></script> 
    <script src="/assets/vendor/libs/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/vendor/libs/hammer/hammer.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/vendor/libs/select2/select2.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="/assets/vendor/libs/tagify/tagify.js"></script>-->
    <script src="/assets/vendor/libs/bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.js"></script>    
    <script src="/assets/vendor/js/menu.js"></script>     
    
    
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- Vendors JS -->
    <script src="/assets/vendor/libs/apex-charts/apexcharts.js"></script>
```

and my coding part in header component files is below. In this file only I'm calling the menus part. Menus are showing fine...but its relevant submenus are not showing.

```
<ul class="menu-inner py-1">
          <!-- Dashboard -->
          <li class="menu-item">            
            <a href="#" class="menu-link menu-toggle">
              <i class="menu-icon tf-icons bx bxs-book-reader" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="Course Master"></i>
              <div data-i18n="Course Master">Course</div>
            </a>
            <ul class="menu-sub">
              <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="manage-course.html" class="menu-link">
                      <div data-i18n="Manage Course">Manage Course</div>
                    </a>
              </li>
              <li class="menu-item">
                <a href="approve-course-master-list.html" class="menu-link">
                  <div data-i18n="Approve Course">Approve Course</div>
                </a>
              </li>
          </ul>
          </li>
</ul>
```